# How to rerun script after Ajax call loads more search results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to implement Klevu's search results page and for the most part, it is easy enough. The issue is that the search results page is showing an Add to Cart button that it shouldn't be, confirmed by Klevu. They suggested that I hide it with CSS and I wrote the below script:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", () =>{
document.querySelectorAll('.kuProdAdditional').forEach(item => item.parentNode.removeChild(item));
})
</script>
```

This script worked no problem, but now I was asked to add in their infinite scrolling script in the head, which was easy. The new problem is that the infinite scrolling makes an Ajax call (I think) and loads the initial results plus the second page and so on. This means that all results, even the original ones, now have the add to cart again. Basically I need help making my script run each time that Ajax call is completed.

The thing is that I have no way to modify that Ajax call so that it runs my script after. Is there a way to detect when the page reloads so I can run my script? I am not a developer, just someone in IT asked to do this.

Comment: put your "hide cart" code in a function and call it again after the ajax is done.

Comment: `hide it with CSS` - maybe you can just add `.kuProdAdditional { display: none }` to your css somewhere and not have to run scripts?

Comment: Do you have access to the AJAX call?

Comment: Aside: `item.parentNode.removeChild(item)` can be simplified to just `item.remove()`.

Comment: You can do [Long Polling](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-long-polling-korvage-szdkf/).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect changes in the DOM using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) that listens on the container for changes in its children list.

```js
const parentContainer = document.getElementById('parentContainer');
const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const newChild = document.createElement('div');
  newChild.innerHTML = 'New Child → <span class="kuProdAdditional">remove me</span> ← removed';
  parentContainer.appendChild(newChild);
});

const mutationCallback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.kuProdAdditional').forEach(item => item.remove())
    }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);

observer.observe(parentContainer, {
  childList: true
});
```

```css
.kuProdAdditional {
  /* ideally: 
  display: none;
  */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentContainer">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>

<button id="addButton">Add Child</button>
```