# Problem with editing HTML in Wordpress Website, with Elementor page builder

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

So, in the website I have, which is [ZINBLO](https://zinblo.com/) I am trying to edit the text in the checkout page, namely in the order review.

The Order Total is showing both currency symbol and currency name.
This is because of the GTranslate plugin, which I am using for free, and manually editing stuff through CSS, like:

E.g.

```
/*TO HIDE CURRENT TEXT*/
button.woocommerce-button.button.woocommerce-form-login__submit.e-woocommerce-form-login-submit.elementor-animation-shrink {
    font-size: 0px;
}

/*TO APPLY MY EDITED OPTION*/
:lang(en) button.woocommerce-button.button.woocommerce-form-login__submit.e-woocommerce-form-login-submit.elementor-animation-shrink::before {
    content: 'Login  ' !important;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Now, this plugin is adding this extra currency name next to the currency symbol.
Check picture 1 and 2 in attachment for context.

I WANT TO HIDE THE EXTRA CURRENCY NAME SHOWN, LEAVING THE THE AMOUNT, AND THE CURRENCY SYMBOL.

I tried everything from JS to CSS and HTML but no results.
It seems that it can be fixed with a simple solution, but I am an amateur and I need help.

[FOR ENGLISH / AUTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qo0q.png) 
[FOR GERMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLnb3.png)

I want to hide the extre currency name, and just keep amount and currency symbol.
Tried CSS, Javascript and HTML.

Comment: the text is translated after page is loaded, so you need to listen for changes to the `.order-total` element using a MutationObserver ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77970800/3807365)). Then run your code which you tried, that removes the currency name.

Answer (score 0):

Check the specific element or class that is wrapping the currency name you want to hide.

Which can be span, div or other element with a class or id.

After identifying the element then set the CSS rule display to 'none'.

```
.class-name {
display:none !important;
 }
```

Since you're using Elementor, you can add this CSS rule in several ways
Through Elementor, Custom Plugin or Site Wide CSS.

If the currency name is being dynamically translated and you need to target specific languages, you can use the :lang() pseudo-class in your CSS.

```
:lang(en) .class-name {
display: none !important;
```

}

```
:lang(de) .class-name {
display: none !important;
```

}